# while focus in Textbox of webview, keyboard is overlaping the textbox in android kendo Ui mobile scheduler

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, webview, kendo-ui

I have created one custom template for kendo UI mobile scheduler control. This control is working fine in iPhone. But in my Android it raises problems.

In my application I am calling the control by loading it on the `webview`. When opening the custom template for inserting or updating the keyboard is overlappping the text boxes.

I tried with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and `"adjustPan"` but didn't fix it.

I am also enabled the `javaScript`.
while I am trying with simple `html` it's working properly.

When am I modifying the custom template(using `jQuery`) keyboard hides my text boxes.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using? Did you try with the latest build? (Q1 Beta - 2014.1.216)?

Comment: 2013.3.1324 Trail version

Comment: Its a bug that can be reproduced in the online beta demos as well. Will be fixed with an internal build later on